# Dropdown selected options not displaying on Safari iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, select, safari

Using jQuery, I'm trying to change the selected option in a SELECT element dynamically. It's working fine on Chrome/IE on windows but not working on iPad/Safari.

Here is my code:

```
$("#ddlRegion").find('option').attr("selected",false).prop('selected', false);
$("#cicddlRegion option[value='" + currCode + "']").attr('selected', 'selected').prop('selected',true);
```

HTML After rendered:

```
<select id="ddlRegion" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="0"> </option>
        <option value="ABR">Abruzzo</option>
        <option value="AG">Agrigento</option>
        <option value="AL">Alessandria</option>
        <option value="AN">Ancona</option>
        <option value="AO">Aosta</option>
        <option value="AR">Arezzo</option>
        <option value="AP">Ascoli Piceno</option>
        <option value="AT">Asti</option>
        <option value="AV">Avellino</option>
        <option value="BA">Bari</option>
        <option value="BT">Barletta-Andria-Trani</option>
        <option value="BAS">Basilicata</option>
        <option value="BL">Belluno</option>
        <option value="BN">Benevento</option>
        <option value="BG">Bergamo</option>
        <option value="BI">Biella</option>
        <option value="BO">Bologna</option>
        <option value="BZ">Bolzano</option>
        <option value="BS">Brescia</option>
        <option value="BR">Brindisi</option>
        <option value="CA">Cagliari</option>
        <option value="CAL">Calabria</option>
        <option value="CL">Caltanissetta</option>
        <option value="CAM">Campania</option>
        <option value="CB">Campobasso</option>
        <option value="CI">Carbonia-Iglesias</option>
        <option value="CE">Caserta</option>
        <option value="CT">Catania</option>
        <option value="CZ">Catanzaro</option>
        <option value="CH">Chieti</option>
        <option value="CO">Como</option>
        <option value="CS">Cosenza</option>
        <option value="CR">Cremona</option>
        <option value="KR">Crotone</option>
        <option value="CN">Cuneo</option>
        <option value="EMI">Emilia-Romagna</option>
        <option value="EN">Enna</option>
        <option value="FM">Fermo</option>
        <option value="FE">Ferrara</option>
        <option value="FI">Firenze</option>
        <option value="FG">Foggia</option>
        <option value="FO">Forli</option>
        <option value="FC">Forlì-Cesena</option>
        <option value="FRI">Friuli-Venezia Giulia</option>
        <option value="FR">Frosinone</option>
        <option value="GE">Genova</option>
        <option value="GO">Gorizia</option>
        <option value="GR">Grosseto</option>
        <option value="IM">Imperia</option>
        <option value="IS">Isernia</option>
        <option value="SP">La Spezia</option>
        <option value="AQ">L'Aquila</option>
        <option value="LT">Latina</option>
        <option value="LAZ">Lazio</option>
        <option value="LE">Lecce</option>
        <option value="LC">Lecco</option>
        <option value="LIG">Liguria</option>
        <option value="LI">Livorno</option>
        <option value="LO">Lodi</option>
        <option value="LOM">Lombardia</option>
        <option value="LU">Lucca</option>
        <option value="MC">Macerata</option>
        <option value="MN">Mantova</option>
        <option value="MAR">Marche</option>
        <option value="MS">Massa</option>
        <option value="MT">Matera</option>
        <option value="VS">Medio Campidano</option>
        <option value="ME">Messina</option>
        <option value="MI">Milano</option>
        <option value="MO">Modena</option>
        <option value="MOL">Molise</option>
        <option value="MB">Monza e della Brianza</option>
        <option value="NA">Napoli</option>
        <option value="NO">Novara</option>
        <option value="NU">Nuoro</option>
        <option value="OG">Ogliastra</option>
        <option value="OT">Olbia-Tempio</option>
        <option value="OR">Oristano</option>
        <option value="PD">Padova</option>
        <option value="PA">Palermo</option>
        <option value="PR">Parma</option>
        <option value="PV">Pavia</option>
        <option value="PG">Perugia</option>
        <option value="PS">Pesaro</option>
        <option value="PU">Pesaro and Urbino</option>
        <option value="PE">Pescara</option>
        <option value="PC">Piacenza</option>
        <option value="PIE">Piemonte</option>
        <option value="PI">Pisa</option>
        <option value="PT">Pistoia</option>
        <option value="PN">Pordenone</option>
        <option value="PZ">Potenza</option>
        <option value="PO">Prato</option>
        <option value="PUG">Puglia</option>
        <option value="RG">Ragusa</option>
        <option value="RA">Ravenna</option>
        <option value="RC">Reggio Calabria</option>
        <option value="RE">Reggio Emilia</option>
        <option value="RI">Rieti</option>
        <option value="RN">Rimini</option>
        <option value="RM" selected="selected">Roma</option>
        <option value="RO">Rovigo</option>
        <option value="Sm">S.m. Del Soccorso</option>
        <option value="SA">Salerno</option>
        <option value="SAR">Sardegna</option>
        <option value="SS">Sassari</option>
        <option value="SV">Savona</option>
        <option value="SIC">Sicilia</option>
        <option value="SI">Siena</option>
        <option value="SR">Siracusa</option>
        <option value="SO">Sondrio</option>
        <option value="TA">Taranto</option>
        <option value="TE">Teramo</option>
        <option value="TR">Terni</option>
        <option value="TO">Torino</option>
        <option value="TOS">Toscana</option>
        <option value="TP">Trapani</option>
        <option value="TRE">Trentino-Alto Adige</option>
        <option value="TN">Trento</option>
        <option value="TV">Treviso</option>
        <option value="TS">Trieste</option>
        <option value="UD">Udine</option>
        <option value="UMB">Umbria</option>
        <option value="VAL">Valle D'Aosta</option>
        <option value="VA">Varese</option>
        <option value="VEN">Veneto</option>
        <option value="VE">Venezia</option>
        <option value="VB">Verbania</option>
        <option value="VC">Vercelli</option>
        <option value="VR">Verona</option>
        <option value="VV">Vibo Valentia</option>
        <option value="VI">Vicenza</option>
        <option value="VT">Viterbo</option>
    </select>
```

On iPad/Safari, I noticed that the target value was selected (checked) `<option value="RM" selected="selected">Roma</option>` but not displaying. any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show your both select-box html (select rendered html on browser by enspecting element through console).Add that in your question